# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not working in mozila

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, colorbox, scriptmanager

I am trying to open jquery colorbox from code behind cs file. It works in chrome but mozila or internet explorer its not working

.aspx code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenColorBox() {
            $.colorbox({
                opacity: 0.1,
                width: '350px',
                height: '350px',
                iframe: true,
                href: 'Test.aspx',
                onLoad: function () {

                    $('#cboxClose').remove();
                },
            });
        }

    </script>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save this Search Criteria" CssClass="srchBtn btnNew"
            OnClick="Call_Click" />
```

.cs File

```
 protected void Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "alert", "OpenColorBox(); return false;", true);
}
```

What i missing in this???If anyone have any idea about it than please help me in this.

Comment: Are you calling that cs code on `Call_Click` ??

Comment: @yogi: I have written Script manager code inside Call_Click event

Comment: Thanks all....I found the issue. It was  silly mistake I have changed my code with this line....`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "alert", "OpenColorBox();", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Call_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
              ((Button)sender),
              ((Button)sender).GetType(),
              "alert", 
              "OpenColorBox();return false;",
              true);
}
```